# Selenium Python - Element Interception Error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am getting the below error while executing my automation code.

```
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x04930850>
response = {'status': 400, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"element click intercepted","message":"element click intercepted: Element ...\n\\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76EE8944+228]\\n\\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76EE8914+180]\\n"}}'}
```

It does not happen everytime, sometimes on executing the script this error is observed, while at times, without making any change, it executes all the test cases correctly.

Comment: The web page may not be loading to completion before you perform a click. Do you have a sleep timer before your selenium click executes?

Comment: Selenium has this weird thing where it can click on an element that overlays the element you're clicking on. If the element you're trying to click is somewhere down the page and isn't currently visible, it'll scroll down until this element is right at the bottom of the page - exactly where all kinds of popups and ads are - so it ends up clicking one of these other elements. This can be solved by clicking the element with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I was also facing the same issue. When you are trying to fetch the URL using the get() function is without the http request try to put **http:// as a prefix**, this is necessary because how python is going to know which protocol you are using to get your request.